# XML-файл, запись в файл, отправка файла по почте

Tags: c#, xml, smtp

есть функция, которая записывает в XML-файл информацию о БД:

```
public static async Task Connection()
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionData))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(@"C:\Users\Николай\source\repos\Junior Backend Test\Junior Backend 
            Test\Result.xml");
            XmlElement? xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;

            XmlElement dbDataElem = xDoc.CreateElement("databasedata");

            XmlText dbConnText = xDoc.CreateTextNode($"Строка подключения: {connection.ConnectionString}");
            XmlText dbStateText = xDoc.CreateTextNode($"Состояние: {connection.State}");
            XmlElement dbConnElem = xDoc.CreateElement("connection");
            XmlElement dbStateElem = xDoc.CreateElement("state");


            dbConnElem.AppendChild(dbConnText);
            dbStateElem.AppendChild(dbStateText);

            dbDataElem.AppendChild(dbConnElem);
            dbDataElem.AppendChild(dbStateElem);

            xRoot?.AppendChild(dbDataElem);
            xDoc.Save(@"C:\Users\Николай\source\repos\Junior Backend Test\Junior Backend Test\Result.xml");
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Так же, есть функция, которая этот файл отсылает на почту:

```
    private static string mailFrom = "";
    private static string mailPassword = "";
    private static string nameMail = "";
    private static string mailTo = "";
    public static async Task SendToMail()
    {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(mailFrom, nameMail);

        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(mailTo);

        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to))
        {
            mail.Subject = "Отправка XML-файла";

            mail.Body = "<h3>Здравствуйте, я отправляю вам файл со списком доступности сайтов.</h3>";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\Users\Николай\source\repos\Junior Backend Test\Junior Backend Test\Result.xml"));

            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
            {
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mailFrom, mailPassword);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Сообщение отправлено!");
    }
```

Проблема в том, когда я вызываю функцию записи данных в файл, то она успешно записывает их. Но, стоит мне после вызвать функцию отправки этого файла на почту, то функция Connection(которая записывает данные в файл) в дебаге просто пропускает строку сохранения данных. Помогите пожалуйста, вообще нет мыслей по поводу этой проблемы.

```
  var stateBD = PostgresqlConnection.Connection().GetAwaiter();

  var sendFile = SendFile.SendToMail().GetAwaiter();
```

Comment: `await PostgresqlConnection.Connection(); await SendFile.SendToMail();`

Comment: Если вы используете `GetAwaiter()`, то либо вы точно знаете что делаете, и у вас не должно быть вопросов, либо вам нельзя его использовать. Для ожидания асинхронных операций и получения результата есть `await`. C `GetAwaiter()` можно знакомиться когда уже с уверенностью владеете асинхронным программированием, то есть `async/await` - не магия, а вы точно знаете как это работает, но не раньше.